# Add an image/signature to an existing pdf file via Node.JS

Tags: node.js, pdf

I looking for way to insert image to an existing pdf file with node.js.
I got the X and Y from the client and want to take the coordinates and insert the image on the pdf file on the server (Node.JS). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the end my solution was to create a separate service on php and work with FPDF and FPDI library, then my Node.JS server send request to the php
service that handle the request.